# Micronaut : No bean introspection available for external class

Tags: serialization, micronaut, introspection, micronaut-serde

Introspection error while trying to import class from external lib.

Steps to reproduce :
Using a common DTO from a shared lib which has micronaut annotation processing enabled.

```
@Data
@Serdeable.Deserializable
public class HeaderABC {
  private Map<String, Object> headerAttrib;
}
```

The serviceHeader from the lib is imported in the micronaut project.

```
@Data
@Serdeable.Deserializable
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RequestA {
  Header header;
}
```

While trying to run the application, we are getting No bean introspection available for external class. [Header] which is dependent lib.

```
Internal Server Error: No bean introspection available for type [class HeaderABC]. Ensure the class is annotated with io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected
```

Below changes didn't help fix it.

- Adding @Introspected in HeaderABC
- annotate RequestA with @SerdeImport(HeaderABC.class)